# Confused about the ordering of results

Tags: solr

I am using Adobe AEM V5.6 with Solr V4.2 and I have a question about the results ranking

See the SERP here - http://www-a4.staging.mcdonalds.com/us/en/search/search_results.html?search=simple&queryText=big&collection=usmcd

My question is why the document 'home' ranks higher than the document 'big mac' the search query appears only once in 'home' but several times in 'Big Mac' and in fields that are being boosted

I can send over the schema and config files if they would be useful

Any thoughts would be very welcome

Thanks, Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Solr logs, you should be able to see the query that Solr receives. Now, copy and paste that query in the browser's address bar with an additional parameter (alternatively)

- fl=*,[explain]
- queryDebug=true

You will see how Solr "sees" the query, and the score computation for each match

Comment: Thanks Andrea! - I see the score computations and I am working on how they relate to the results

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend using http://explain.solr.pl/explains/new for analyzing the query result you've get with queryDebug=true